# Is the AWS Cognito User Status "ARCHIVED" set by AWS or by user request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Looking at Cognito docs I can't seem to find any explanation of what the ARCHIVED status is for and whether it's something set by Cognito under certain circumstances, for example if user does not log into their account after a certain period of time or whether it's completely dependent on the developer to set! I need a better understanding of ARCHIVED so that I can leverage this status in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ARCHIVED` state is currently not used by Amazon Cognito. It is just written as a  placeholder in the documentation, and it may be used later in the future. For now, you can develop your Authentication Engine without worrying about the state.

AWS Premium Support would be able to confirm the same.

Comment: Is there a away for me to manually set a user status to ARCHIVED?

Comment: No, there is not. It may be used by Amazon Cognito in the future. For now, ARCHIVED is just mentioned in the documentation and that's it.